# Best way to port java script array push json to c++ syntax

Tags: javascript, c++, porting

i trying to think what is the best way to port this javascript syntecs to standart c++ one

this is the js code:

```
 segments = [];
    segments.push({
               index: n,
               p1: { world: { z:  n   *segmentLength }, camera: {}, screen: {} },
               p2: { world: { z: (n+1)*segmentLength }, camera: {}, screen: {} },
               color: Math.floor(n/rumbleLength)%2 ? COLORS.DARK : COLORS.LIGHT
            });
```

i dont understand which structure or structures should be after the index in the c++ vector?
i dont what it to build json , but convert the json to struct , an in here is the problem .
im not sure what is the right way to convert this json to struct .

for example is this right way to represent p1:

```
struct p1
{
   struct world {
         world::world()
         {
          z =  n   *segmentLength;
         }
         int z

   };
   int camera[MAX];
   int screen[MAX];
}
```

Comment: Write yourself a set of classes to represent the different data-types that are in javascript represented by associative arrays. Use a std::vector in place of the array.

Comment: if camera add some child data in later, your struct should be change, IMHO, use structure to translate json is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `std::vector` whose element is a json object, C++ also has a well support 3rd-party libray for [JSON](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/).

```
std::vector<Json::Value> vec;
Json::Value m;
...                   //set m with proper key, value
vec.push_back(m)
```

Comment: i dont want to use json , i like to convert it to struct , but what is the right way ...?

Comment: In that way, you should define struct for your json key, ex. struct a{ int z; }, if your json has so many levels, the struct number will become much.

Comment: It's a little misleading to say that "C++ supports JSON", but that's a good 3rd party library. Anyway, this isn't what was asked for.

Comment: Thanks, I will update it. Yes, I answer before OP modify the requirement. :(